# Couldn't match expected type while doing file IO

Tags: haskell, io

I'm trying to write a function that loads all files in a directory into a [ByteString], by calling loadFile on each element in the list that comes from getDirectoryContents

Right now I've got this:

```
import Data.ByteString
import System.Directory
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

loadFile :: String -> IO B.ByteString
loadFile fileName = withFile fileName ReadMode (\handle -> hGetContents handle)

loadFiles :: String -> IO [IO B.ByteString]
loadFiles x = return (map (loadFile) $ getDirectoryContents x)
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
main.hs:28:60:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `B.ByteString'
    Expected type: IO B.ByteString
      Actual type: IO String
    In the return type of a call of `hGetContents'
    In the expression: hGetContents handle
    In the third argument of `withFile', namely
      `(\ handle -> hGetContents handle)'
```

I am very new to haskell (I started learning yesterday) so this error message is confusing to me. I expected it to infer the type B.ByteString since that is part of the return value of loadFile. Also any comments on style/convention are welcome

Comment: `loadFiles` does not actually read any files. It constructs the `IO` actions which can later be executed to read the files. `loadFiles x = getDirectoryContents x >>= mapM loadFile` will actually read the files.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `hGetContents` from `System.IO`, which returns an `IO String`. You probably want to be using `B.hGetContents` from `Data.ByteString`, which returns an `IO ByteString`.

The reason I know this is because the error message says it expects `IO B.ByteString`, but it has `IO String`, "In the return type of a call of `hGetContents`."